# Can a class inherited from Qthread behave as a normal class?

Tags: qt

Can a class inherited from QThread and having run method can have other methods and can it be used like another normal ( not inherited from QThread) class?

Comment: what do you mean by normal class? how is it not "normal"? if what you mean is can you have other methods and call them from run() then yes.

Comment: can we have other methods and not call them from run,but using the object?

Comment: yes, the question is why would you want to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a class that inherits from QThread is still a normal class. However, care must be taken to [synchronize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronization_(computer_science)) calls to member functions that occur in a different thread context (i.e. calls from outside of the run method) as necessary. Read about [Thread Support in Qt](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/threads.html) for more details. [Herb Sutter](http://herbsutter.wordpress.com/) has a nice [collection of articles discussing different aspects of concurrency](http://herbsutter.wordpress.com/category/concurrency/) as well.